# ARM assembly language: caesar cypher

Tags: arm, character

*This is for homework*

I have to take a given string and offset as parameters and create an encrypted version of the string. Here is what I have so far

```
.global
cypher:
    stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr} @std
    mov v1, a1             @hold the string pointer in v1
    bl strlen              @get the length of the string in a1
    add a1, a1, #1         @add null byte space to strlen
    mov v2, a1             @hold the length of space needed in v2
    bl malloc              @reserve space for new string in a1
    mov v3, #0             @initial index of new string
loop:ldr v4, [v1], #4      @load v4 with string pointer and increment by bytes
    add v5, v4, a2         @add the offset to the current character
    str v5, [a1, v3]       @store the new character in the new address
    add v3, v3, #4         @increment the index by a byte
    cmp v2, v3
    bne loop
    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc} @std     
    .end
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually increment the character correctly. How to I add an offset to a character?(I'm guessing the ascii characters need to be incremented?)

Comment: Yes they do.  Then for decryption, you just subtract the correct offset.  But I can see that is what you are doing in your code.  So what is the outcome of your code?

Comment: The string tested is "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG" The string I get is "XHE UUICO BRSWN JOX NUMPW OVIR TLE LEZY HOG" It seems to be skipping 3 characters in between changing a character

Comment: I think it's because you are skipping 4 bytes.  Can you try changing your two sets of #4 to #1s?

Comment: No success with that. The same thing happens just shifted to the left one character it seems. Still skipping 3 characters in between. Also a2 (the second parameter that holds the offset) seems to give a weird offset and I am currently hard-coding with a fixed offset of 4. Any ideas on what is happening with a2?

Comment: Strange that it skips 3 characters.  And you are sure you have removed all #4?  Try changing your hardcoded offset to something like 7.  What happens then?  Your offsetting functionality is actually working correct, I think the issue is with v3.

Comment: hmmm I tried a different offset but still have the same issue.I'm guessing something on the other end is causing the issue because the code looks right to me too.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the loop by four bytes.

Below is the "correct" one: (and an optimize one, too: you don't need v3 and v5)

```
loop:ldrb v4, [v1], #1      @load v4 with string pointer and increment by bytes
    subs v2, v2, #1
    add v4, v4, a2         @add the offset to the current character
    strb v4, [a1], #1       @store the new character in the new address
    bne loop

    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc} @std
```